# create path to excel file on network drive

Tags: c#

I want to get my program to link to an excel doc on a network drive. If I set my path to the local drive of the computer the program works fine, but not when the path is set to the network drive.

Here's my code with the path:

```
MessageBox.Show("test3");
string pat = @"\\192.168.1.2\programmer\tidsregistrering\program\brugere.xlsx";

Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pat);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
MessageBox.Show("test4");
```

The error code says that the path maybe don't exist, but I have double check and check again and there is no spelling error...

If it helps it take forever for the error to come, it's like the program are trying to connect to the network drive but dosen't get allowed.

The MessageBox'es "test3" and "test4" is just for testing where the program is in the process.

Comment: Can you access the path from `Explorer` ?

Comment: Make sure the excel file you are trying to access is not opened by any other programs

Comment: You should include your exact error message.  You should also try pasting "\\192.168.1.2\programmer\tidsregistrering\program" into a windows explorer address bar to make sure your path is correct.

Comment: the excel doc are not open..

Comment: hmm the path dosen't open,,, hmm I don't understand that, the IP of the server is 192.168.1.2, and the drive on the server is named programmer (E:)

Comment: ARH, stupid me,, if I change the path from: "string pat = @"\\192.168.1.2\programmer\tidsregistrering\program\brugere.xlsx";" to "string pat = @"\\192.168.1.2\e\tidsregistrering\program\brugere.xlsx";" then it worked, I thought it was the "name" of the drive like when you have to map a network drive..  Well thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could try "\\192.168.1.2\e$\programmer\tidsregistrering\program", but that will only work if you are a local admin. I would suggest you need to set up a network share. You also need to take into consideration on whose login will this program be running when it is deployed. When it works for you in development, will it work for the average user who must run the program?

Comment: It should only work on local computers, so that's not a problem...
I have set up a network share, but the program, will it not use the login from the computer which already logged in to the network share ?

Comment: Network Shared Drives **may** not have the same names as physical drives. The [NET SHARE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490712.aspx) command will display the shared names for your drives.